# Missing Integration Services option in SSMS

Tags: service, integration, sql-server-2008

I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition on a box that already had SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition installed in it.
Now Integration Services will not show up in the connect drop-down menu in the object explorer. 
Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to run SSMS as administrator and it gave me a choice of all services during login.

Comment: Express will not do SSIS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15514572/153923

Answer (score 7):

2 Possibilities spring to mind:

- You are using Management Studio Express which doesn't support SSIS
- You have done what I just did & have installed "Management Tools basic" & left out "Management tools - complete"

Either way the solution is to run a SQL 2008 install (not express), choose "add features" & check "management tools - complete"

Comment: Does express say express somewhere?

Comment: Connect to your local instance and run: SELECT @@Version

Answer (score 4):

There's another angle to this one. If you have SQL Server 2008 already installed, you need to select the upgrade option. If you don't, then in your installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 your "management tools - complete" will be grayed out when you get to the install items choice screen. Hover over it and it will tell you as much. Hope this helps someone.