# SQL Server 2008 Express Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2008-express

Does SQL Server 2008 Express support Integration Services? When I try to create an Integration Services project, it says that I have to install Integration Services, but I cannot find the option in the setup for the installation. How can I install it? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not. From [Features Supported by the Editions of SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

[image: ok]

You need to be running at least Standard Edition.

Comment: Thanks! Esp. for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express doesn't support Integration Services at it's fullest. It will support,  access to basic data sources, but not the full suite that is included in the Standard edition of MSSQL Server 2008.

I don't believe there is a way around this. It's part of the installation package and I don't believe Express has the necessary programmatic pieces for Integration Services.